# Calling off meetings with bosses

Tags: communication

I have a very senior "dotted-line" boss. I'm not reporting to him, but he should know generally, what I'm up to.

It's me who normally need to chase him or his assistant for a meeting. We currently have a few scheduled. He himself has never requested a meeting with me.

Additionally, he tends to call off our planned 1:1s a lot, quoting lack of time.

Since my actual boss now considerably reduced my number of tasks and stopped my projects I currently don't have much to update my dotted-line boss about. I'm not sure what I could tell him during our next 1:1 without that sounding as a complain about my boss ("Project A - stopped; Task B - Boss 1 decided I shouldn't work on it"). However, I don't want him to think I'm avoiding him. What's the way to call it off?

Answer (score 3):

**"I know you are busy and I do not have much to tell you"**

He gives you an easy way out. Tell him (or his assistant) that you have very little to report and he can have his hour back. He could probably use it.

Comment: Or you could use the meeting for something useful, like discussing options for professional growth and training ... As a manager, I get nervous when team members say they have nothing to report. That's a sign of potential trouble.

Comment: @Roland both my current and former manager are like that too. Why? It is that strange for all to be well?

Comment: When all is well, team members like talking about their work. They want to be recognized for their good work and that's easiest if you can report how well you are doing. (Introverts need some leading questions.) Unless you schedule these meetings too frequently, there is always something to discuss. However, if there are issues, some people get very vocal about these and some people stop talking.